# How to append a vector to Julia matrix as a row?

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I have an empty matrix initially:

```
m = Matrix(0, 3)
```

and a row that I want to add:

```
v = [2,3]
```

I try to do this:

```
[m v]
```

But I get an error

```
 ERROR: ArgumentError: number of rows of each array must match
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because your matrix sizes don't match. Specifically v does not contain enough columns to match m. And its transposed

So this doesnt work

```
m = Matrix(0, 3)
v = [2,3]
m = cat(1, m, v)  # or a = [m; v]
>> ERROR: DimensionMismatch("mismatch in dimension 2 (expected 3 got 1)")
```

whereas this does

```
m = Matrix(0, 3)
v = [2 3 4]
m = cat(1, m, v)  # or m = [m; v]
>> 1x3 Array{Any,2}:
>>   2  3  4
```

and if you run it again it creates another row

```
m = cat(1, m, v)  # or m = [m; v]
>> 2x3 Array{Any,2}:
>>   2  3  4
>>   2  3  4
```

Comment: Or if you want to maintain your `v = [2,3,4]` format you can append the row using `m = [m; v']`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `vcat` (concatenate vertically) function:

```rb
help?> vcat
search: vcat hvcat VecOrMat DenseVecOrMat StridedVecOrMat AbstractVecOrMat levicivita is_valid_char @vectorize_2arg

  vcat(A...)

  Concatenate along dimension 1
```

Notice you have to transpose the vector `v`, ie. `v'`, else you get a `DimensionMismatch` error:

```rb
julia> v = zeros(3)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> m = ones(3, 3)
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0

julia> vcat(m, v')    # '
4x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0

julia> v'    # '
1x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0

julia> vcat(m, v)
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("mismatch in dimension 2 (expected 3 got 1)")
 in cat_t at abstractarray.jl:850
 in vcat at abstractarray.jl:887
```

**Note:** the comments; `# '` are there just to make syntax highlighting work well.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that `Matrix` creates a  two-dimensional array in Julia? If you try with m =[0, 3], which creates a one-dimensional `Vector` for you, you can append it by `[m; v]`.

I think using `[m v]` is create a two-dimensional array as well, from the Julia Document